# Google Sheets conditional format cell if any of the specified cells are blank

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to format a cell to have white text & white fill if any of several other cells are blank.  I excel, I would use `=OR(K2="",P2="",Q2="",R2="",S2="",T2="",U2="",V2="",W2="",X2="",Y2="",Z2="",AB2="",AF2="")`

This is not working in google sheets.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(OR(isblank({K2,P2,Q2,R2,S2,T2,U2,V2,W2,X2,Y2,Z2,AB2,AF2})))
```

**ISBLANK()** will check if each cell within the provided array is blank.

**OR()** compacts all the results into a single Boolean value. Without it the function will still check every cell you listed but will only change the formatting based on whether or not the first cell, K2, is empty.

**ARRAYFORMULA()** is necessary in order to allow ISBLANK() to take an array as a parameter. It prefers to work with a single cell otherwise.